# None of ['date'] are in the columns

Tags: pandas, numpy

I'm trying to plot some graphs with numpy and plotly. I'm getting the data from a csv file containing all the trends that I need. I want to plot and analyze the values contained in columns 1-80 along the timeframe ("Date")
Here's the script I've written to do that.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

import seaborn as sns

import plotly.express as px

ztec = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tashkpa\Desktop\Работа\ТЭЦ\Сырые данные ЗТЭЦ\данные для python.csv')

ztec=ztec.set_index('Date')

print(ztec)

fig=plt.figure()

ax=fig.add_subplot()

sns.set_style("ticks", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})

sns.lineplot(x=ztec['Date'], y=ztec['01'])

plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--", c='gray')

plt.plot
```

A sample of my array looks like this:

```
'Date';'01';'02';'03';'04';'05';'06';'07';'08';'09';'10';'11';'12';'13';'14';'15';'16';'17';'18';'19';'20';'21';'22';'23';'24';'25';'26';'27';'28';'29';'30';'31';'32';'33';'34';'35';'36';'37';'38';'39';'40';'41';'42';'43';'44';'45';'46';'47';'48';'49';'50';'51';'52';'53';'54';'55';'56';'57';'58';'59';'60';'61';'62';'63';'64';'65';'66';'67';'68';'69';'70';'71';'72';'73';'74';'75';'76';'77';'78';'79';'80';;;;;;;;;;;;;
01/01/2021 02:00:00;0.791;7.019;199.265;183.586;506.253;5.641;41.729;212.521;0.528;0.115;32.356;35.264;0.788;208.541;0.356;0.348;0.087;3.887;3.483;8.784;31.930;13.237;24.296;13.552;23.546;36.840;36.978;218.913;35.373;0.860;0.147;0.319;115.694;0.785;7.064;201.466;183.316;509.751;5.721;42.600;210.235;0.563;12.276;60.000;135.939;0.784;206.678;0.347;0.334;0.066;3.959;4.138;4.821;8.027;13.494;18.367;13.702;18.536;30.446;31.199;243.470;1.908;0.901;2.082;0.216;106.911;3.681;-1.484;205.884;284.659;146.202;3.681;-9.315;56.252;54.483;40195.012;39724.953;102.121;128.471;102.573;;;;;;;;;;;;;
```

Here's the exception that Python fires.

```
C:\Users\tashkpa\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py", line 7, in <module>
    ztec=ztec.set_index('Date')
  File "C:\Users\tashkpa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4724, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"
```

How could I bypass this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- By default `pd.read_csv` use a default value for `sep=','`
- In this case use `sep=';'` when using `pd.read_csv`, since the value separator is `;`
- Since you have set `Date` column as index using `ztec=ztec.set_index('Date')`, you have to use the `ztec.index` as `x` when plotting `sns.lineplot(x=ztec.index, y=ztec['01'])`

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import plotly.express as px
    
ztec = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\tashkpa\Desktop\Работа\ТЭЦ\Сырые данные ЗТЭЦ\данные для python.csv', sep=';')
ztec=ztec.set_index('Date')
print(ztec)
    
fig=plt.figure()
ax=fig.add_subplot()
sns.set_style("ticks", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})
sns.lineplot(x=ztec.index, y=ztec['01'])
plt.grid(True, which="both", ls="--", c='gray')
plt.plot()
```

Comment: @PavelTashkinov what seem to the problem ? Do you see a error message?

Comment: C:\Users\tashkpa\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py", line 7, in <module>
    ztec=ztec.set_index('Date')
  File "C:\Users\tashkpa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4724, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: @PavelTashkinov can you run `ztec.columns` and comment the output ?

Comment: C:\Users\tashkpa\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py
Index([''Date';'01';'02';'03';'04';'05';'06';'07';'08';'09';'10';'11';'12';'13';'14';'15';'16';'17';'18';'19';'20';'21';'22';'23';'24';'25';'26';'27';'28';'29';'30';'31';'32';'33';'34';'35';'36';'37';'38';'39';'40';'41';'42';'43';'44';'45';'46';'47';'48';'49';'50';'51';'52';'53';'54';'55';'56';'57';'58';'59';'60';'61';'62';'63';'64';'65';'66';'67';'68';'69';'70';'71';'72';'73';'74';'75';'76';'77';'78';'79';'80';;;;;;;;;;;;;'], dtype='object')

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: can you also include the ouput of `ztex.shape` . I think the whole data is read into one column

Comment: (1416,1). Would it be a good starting point to reshape it?

Comment: @PavelTashkinov, found the problem, please see the updated answer

Comment: Still, it keeps firing the same mistake.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/tashkpa/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/zteccsv.py", line 8, in <module>
    ztec = ztec.set_index('Date')
  File "C:\Users\tashkpa\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4724, in set_index
    raise KeyError(f"None of {missing} are in the columns")
KeyError: "None of ['Date'] are in the columns"

Comment: @PavelTashkinov, please include the output of `ztex.shape` and `ztec.columns`

Comment: ztec.shape (1416, 94)

Comment: ztec.shape (1416, 94)
ztec.columns Index([''Date''; ''01'';''02''; ''03'; ''04'';''05''; ''06''; ''07'';...;
       ''80''; "Unnamed: 93"],
      dtype='object')

Answer (score 0):

I too received this error, but for me i was trying to set Index as 'Date' where it was already.

So, Once the index is set to a field eg: 'Date', the same code will show the similar error.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34326626)